Name for a dendrogram showing how variable clustering affects variance explained
This is from Harrell's RMS:

I'm sure I have seen a similar dendrogram used to illustrate the effect of variable clustering on $R$ / $R^2$. It was plotted with the x, y axes the other way round to the graph just shown, but otherwise looked very similar. Rather than having $\rho^2$ on an axis, it had $R$ or $R^2$, so that you could see how combining variables reduced $R^2$.
I have tried every search term I can think of but cannot find the specific name for such a dendrogram or what package might generate it. Does anyone know?
Edit: it's VARCLUS.


I haven't seen anything quite like that.  Usually $R^2$ assessments are done on the contribution each variable adds to the whole, supplemented by $R^2$ from chunk tests combining the effect of pre-specified groups of variables.  I've been meaning for years to write code that would automatically group collinear predictors and generate the chunk tests in anova().  But we'd need to select a criterion for making the grouping decision.

I found it -- it's VARCLUS. See e.g. plot at very end of https://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/stat/chap68/sect21.htm . It's not what I wanted, though -- I was hoping for something that had R^2s for individual variables at the leaves of the tree.

What I was referring to was relative $R^2$ for a entire branch of the tree if there were to be a solid definition for what a branch consists of.
